# VIewDidLoad is called but view is not loading

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

I am trying to load `ViewController` on button action but it does not load in iPhone.

```
- (IBAction)SubmitTapped:(id)sender
{
    if([txtName.text isEqualToString:@"User"])
    {
        NSLog(@"It is User");
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *soapMessage = @"";

        ThirdVC *thirdVCObj = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushToThirdVC"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdVCObj animated:YES];

        [self generalParsing:@"" :soapMessage];

        [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Note:- I have confirmed that my `UIViewController` class name ok & `storyboard id` is ok in code otherwise it will crash, When I make my First `VC RootView` of `UINavigationController` than it does not load my `ThirdVC` on click of `SecondVC`'s button action but when I assign `RootView` of `UINavigationController` to my `SecondVC` then it loads my `Third VC`.

I tried placing my above Two lines of Push code to my Web Service parsing class but it does not load there also.

My `viewDidLoad` & `viewWillAppear` is being called, i set log in these methods.

I have searched all possible questions here on `StackOverFlow` but I did not find any solution.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
enter code here
```

[image: My Snap For StoryBoard]

Comment: What do you see if you put `NSLog(@"New controller %@, Navigation controller %@", thirdVCObj, self.navigationController);` just before the `pushViewController`?

Comment: @PhillipMills  New controller <ThirdVC: 0x17ee47f0>, Navigation controller <UINavigationController: 0x17dae460>

Comment: @JayminRaval Try to log navigationcontrollers.viewcontrollers.count if u get 0 then i will explain further.

Comment: @Dany Tried This 

        NSLog(@"Counts %lu ",(unsigned long)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);

Got This:- Counts 3

Comment: @JayminRaval Just to give a shot, try to present your thirdVC by keeping your FirstVC as rootViewController. So it wil be like Root-->First-->Push-->second-->present-->third

Comment: @Dany it Works that way :) but not able to push.. I need to push it because that ThirdVC is pushing other ViewControllers in my app.

Comment: Can u paste your storyboard complete snap and file inspector of your rootViewController

Comment: move [self generalParsing:@"" :soapMessage];

        [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; above [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdVCObj animated:YES];

Comment: @CharanGiri it is not working that way.

Comment: i go for @l0gg3r answer. I tried that too. It works fine. Do u use anything like performSelector or blocks anywhere?

Comment: @Dany no, when didEndElement method for xml parser is called i tried to push to ViewController according to Results when push did not worked on submit button click.

Comment: @Dany i Deleted Both ViewController & made new but still not pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is against to all "Cocoa Coding Guidelines"

I copied this code, to a new project and it works.
The problem makes WebService parser, make sure that pushViewController:animated: is called from main thread.

Try this

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *soapMessage = @"";

        ThirdVC *thirdVCObj = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushToThirdVC"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdVCObj animated:YES];

        [self generalParsing:@"" :soapMessage];

        [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    });
```

Comment: I tried that code on webservice parser because it was not working on my Main Thread Method 

- (IBAction)SubmitTapped:(id)sender
{
}

How it is against to "Cocoa Coding Guidelines"? will you explain please?

Comment: You can read this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html Don't capitalize method names, and generalParsing:@"" :soapMessage , is confusing too. You need to name it parseGeneral:soapMessage:

Comment: You are a life saviour :)